# Windows 7 - How to hide another dual boot partition for one system and still be able to boot?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot

Well I have a dual boot configuration of two Windows 7's (one x64, 450 GB space and one Mini Windows 7 x32 using 3 gb out of 8).
Now, in the main operating system I want to hide the Mini 7 partition but still be able to boot from it (Like the Recovery Partition on my laptop : o). The problem is after I right click the partition in disk manager and remove all it's letters and paths, then after a reboot the boot menu doesn't h ave a second entry (so I cannot boot into Mini Windows 7). When I restore the drive letter in my main Windows 7 system, reboot, it's visible again. Why can't I hide the MiniWin7 partition in my main operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [website](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/hide-drives-from-your-computer-in-windows-vista/) Has a decent walk through on how to hide drive letters in windows 7. But basically have to make a registry entry

```
HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

called NoDrives DWORD . Read the chart on the website to figure out which data to enter for specific drive letters.

Note: You can do it in HKEY_CURRENT_USER but if you have others log on they will see the drive.